# I am having trouble removing a custom UIButton from inside a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When in editing mode, I want the cell to display a uibutton in addition to the editing accessory. When the tableView goes into editing mode, the button appears fine and works fine. But it never gets removed. I have tried saying myButton.hidden = TRUE in addition to the following code. This is what I have in my custom tableViewCell class

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    self.trashButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.trashButton.frame = CGRectMake(337, 17, 27, 30);
    [self.trashButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if (editing) {
        [self addSubview:self.trashButton];
    } else {

        [self.trashButton removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you alloc/initing your button before the `if (editing) ` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, doing this may be better:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (self.trashButton) 
    {
        [self.trashButton removeFromSuperview];
        self.trashButton = nil;
    } 
    else 
    {
         self.trashButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         self.trashButton.frame = CGRectMake(337, 17, 27, 30);
         [self.trashButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trash.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

         [self addSubview:self.trashButton];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are recreating the UIButton every time the setEditing method is called. When you call removeFromSuperview, the button being removed is the one you just created a few lines above, and it's not the one added to your UITableViewCell.

Solution: Make the UIButton a class property, initialize it in initWithFrame or awakeFromNib (if using storyboard), then hide it/show it whenever setEditing is called

Comment: Forgot to mention: after you initialize the UIButton, add it to the view and hide it. Then just hide/unhide it in setEditing, but don't use addSubview or removeFromSuperview.